# How does number sense develop in blind people?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, vision, numerical-cognition

From what I understand about number sense and numerical cognition, the visual system is heavily involved in the approximate number system and the object tracking system, which are at the root of number sense and numerical cognition leading to the rest of mathematics. So, how exactly would somebody with a severely impaired or nonfunctional visual system (blindness) develop number sense?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to this interesting site. What do you mean by an approximate number system?

Comment: Make a reference to what you understand (**From what I understand...**).

Comment: @descheleschilder cf. [The Precision and Internal Confidence of Our Approximate Number Thoughts](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780124201330000120) by Halberda and Odic, [Analogical Mapping in Numerical Development](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B978012812574800002X) by Marchand and Barner, and [Understanding the Link Between the Approximate Number System and Math Abilities](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128159521000049) by Libertus.

Comment: Also [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_number_system) where there is an entire section dedicated to the visual cortex's role in the system. Grazie